# Spring upper case format for system properites as environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot docs indirectly mentions that system properties can be "set" via corresponding OS environment variables:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

> Upper case format, which is recommended when using system environment variables.
>
> If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (for example, SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of spring.config.name).
>
> Environment Variables. Upper case format with underscore as the delimiter. _ should not be used within a property name
>
> You should also be aware that, since @Value does not support relaxed binding, it is not a good candidate if you need to provide the value by using environment variables.

I am curious if it is solely feature of Spring Boot or plain Spring also supports upper case env var syntax for sys props?

Comment: spring supports that, spring-boot is just template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestion in comment I dug into for `Environment` source code and found:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.html

> Specialization of MapPropertySource designed for use with system environment variables. **Compensates for constraints in Bash and other shells that do not allow for variables containing the period character and/or hyphen character; also allows for uppercase variations on property names for more idiomatic shell use**.